# Javascript não funciona :(

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Bom dia.

Linkei o javascript em meu site da seguinte forma:

```
script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
```

e um dos códigos é esse, inserido logo após o body, para fixar menu após rolagem:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery("document").ready(function($){

            var nav = $('.menu');

            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
                    nav.addClass("fixar");
                } else {
                    nav.removeClass("fixar");
                }
            });
    </script>
```

Mas nada funciona, já tentei o "olá mundo" para testar o js mas nem isso funciona. Alguém tem ideia do que possa estar funcionando?

Comment: faltam te fechar tags.. no final de tudo nao fechas a funcao inicial.. adiciona outro "});"

Comment: Coloca o Código completo da sua página por favor.

Comment: "*inserido logo após o body*" - E porque você não o coloca **dentro** do `<body>`? Ou melhor ainda, dentro do `<head>`?

Comment: sir_ask realmente era isso. Muito obrigado :)

Comment: Isso parece bem errado `jQuery("document").ready(function($){`, provavelmente você deveria usar `jQuery(document).ready` ou `jQuery.ready`

Answer (score 1):

Amigo a estrutura deve ser como está:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Teste</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  // AGORA QUE O JQUERY FOI IMPORTADO, VOCÊ PODE COMEÇAR A ESCREVER SEUS CÓDIGOS QUE UTILIZAM A BIBLIOTECA.
 <script>
   $(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
   });
 </script>
</html>
```

Não esqueça de levar em consideração separar o Html do Javascript para melhorar a legibilidade.